# AND condition IF-THEN-ELSE statement in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I want to use the [IF-THEN-ELSE statement in PL/SQL](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/loops/if_then.php).

I am writing a procedure and have two `boolean` defined:

```
bool1 BOOLEAN;
bool2 BOOLEAN;
```

Now I am searching for something like

```
IF bool1 AND bool2 THEN
   ...
ELSE
   ...
END IF;
```

But I can't find anything similiar to that in the www.

I'm sure you can help me! ;)

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you already got it. This code will work:

```
set serveroutput on;

DECLARE
   bool1   BOOLEAN;
   bool2   BOOLEAN;
BEGIN
   bool1 := TRUE;
   bool2 := FALSE;

   IF bool1 AND bool2
   THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Both true');
   ELSE
      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Not both true');
   END IF;
END;
```

Be aware though that in oracle booleans only exist in PL/SQL, not in SQL, so you can't have a column of the datatype boolean in the DB.